# Docusign api template: disable email notification to recipient

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using the REST API and I've been creating enveloped manually through code. I prefer that my site retrieve the docusign console links for the recipients so I disabled the emails in the sandbox (preferences->Features) by checking "Suppress Emails to Embedded Signers".

It worked. I switched to building the envelope from a template and now the email notifications are going to the recipients from docusign. There seems to be some stuff in the template part of the API to change subject, body, etc of the emails, but nothing to Suppress them". Is there any way to supress the recipient notificaiton email?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are not adding the clientUserID information when creating these envelopes via template. If you do not specify clientUserID, it will result in a remote signing envelope for that recipient, which will generate emails. If you add the CUID, then it will honor the suppress emails to embedded signers setting.

Comment: Sure enough. It worked! I just didn't see any examples on your site to let me know that when adding TemplateRoles, you could add a clientuserID. I added it and the emails were disabled, just like in my settings. Thanks.